# Default Home page has been changed in backed but not reflecting in frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have migrated my magento2.4 to another host. But the thing is all my pages are changed as per my theme but the homepage showing as luma. I have changed default page section in the admin panel and changed cms pages but not reflecting. What is the issue here?

Thanks in advace

Comment: Can you check your Layout setting in page? check you themes configuration in design Menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear your magento cache.
Go to root directory :
php bin/magento c:f
do reindexing
php bin/magento indexer:reindexing